# Replace comma if in between numbers with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am trying to replace each occurrence of a comma **','** but only if it is found in between two digits/numbers.

E.g. "Text, 10,10 text, 40 text, 10,60" should be returned as "Text, 1010 text, 40 text, 1060", where I replace the comma found between **10,10** and **10,60** but keep the commas after the text.

```js
var text = "Text, 10,10 text, 40 text, 10,60";
var nocomma = text.replace(/,/g, '');
console.log(nocomma);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use capturing groups and replace

```js
var text = "Text, 10,10 text, 40 text, 10,60";
var nocomma = text.replace(/(\d),(\d)/g, '$1$2');

console.log(nocomma);
```

If you're using modern browser which support both  lookbehind you can use this too

```
str.replace(/(?<=\d),(?=\d)/g,'')
```

Comment: This is way more efficient (?<=\d),(?=\d) than /(\d),(\d)/g .

Answer (score 1):

If there can also be multiple occurrences of digits followed by a comma, you could use a single capturing group matching 1+ digits `(\d+)`

Then match a comma and use positive lookahead `(?=` to assert what is directly to the right is a digit `\d`.

In the replacement use the first capturing group `$1`

```
(\d+),(?=\d)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cTsxFV/1)

```js
var text = "Text, 10,10 text, 40 text, 10,60 or 10,10,10";
var nocomma = text.replace(/(\d+),(?=\d)/g, '$1');
console.log(nocomma);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your going to want match your digits and reference them in your replacement text using $n in the string where n is the index of your substring match.  The following should work.
You can see [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for more information on replace and how it works.

```js
let text = "Text, 10,10 text, 40 text, 10,60",
 result = text.replace(/(\d),(\d)/g, '$1$2');
 
console.log(result);
```